# "Interface Locale" admin language problem

Tags: admin, magento-1, localisation, language

In my admin page, the "Interface Locale" dropdown is not working. I already switched the default language to German, but is still shows English. The same with Chinese. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: do you want to change your store or your admin panel?

Comment: I want to change the language to Germen or Chinese of my admin panel, but no matter which language I switch, it is always shows English, only login information and date on the top are change, is something lost?

Comment: I don't have that problem, I just changed my interface locale in the bottom of admin panel and it changes the language for me, maybe you need to reinstall a fresh magento and see if that works or not. or maybe you are using an old magento version?

Comment: Do you have german language installed? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/locale-mage-community-de-de.html

Answer (score 0):

English is the default if no translation package for the selected language is installed.

Some language packs can be found on Magento Connect:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-experience/internationalization-localization.html